# Batch - How to replace string in a %%variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to create a .bat file that might be very easy but I am having a real hard time trying to figure out how to do it.

I need a batch that gets all the files *.ui in the current folder, and executes a program passing two arguments to it: that *.ui file name, and the same file name with this two modifications

- Added ../ in front so the referenced file is in the parent folder
- Replaced file extension from *.ui to *.py

In pseudo:

```
for every file *.ui in this folder as file:
    file2 = "../" + replace( file, ".ui", ".py")
    execute python.exe file -o file2
```

This is the final .bat, but the replacing extensions part is missing:

```
FOR %i IN (*.ui) DO python -m PyQt4.uic.pyuic %i -o (????)
```

I have tried the batch replacing (????) with the file name manually and it works. But how can I add `../` and replace `.ui` to `.py`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FOR %i IN (*.ui) DO python -m PyQt4.uic.pyuic %i -o ..\%~ni.py
```

see `for/?`

Comment: Hi, sorry but I don't understand your answer. What do you mean with see `for/?`. I tried the script and it throws an error. Sorry if this is too newbie for you, but if you could help me with this i would appreciate it very much.

Comment: What does `for %i in (*.bat) do @echo ..\%~ni.py` say? (if you use it in a batchfile, double the `%`: `%%i` and `..\%%~ni.py`)

Comment: This prepends `..\` although `../` was requested -- this might cause trouble with Python...?

Comment: I don't have phyton. Command repetition is fine: `..\filename.py`. Ideas: a) doubling the backslash, b) enclose in quotes: `"..\%~ni"`